# Get array of unique values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

hey there i have a page hits table that looks like:

browser || version || hits || referrer

---

i am already getting the hits array as in:

```
public function get_app_hits_array($app_fb_page_id, $app_type) 
{       
     $app_analytics_hits_sql = "SELECT * FROM `analytics_hits` WHERE `fb_page_id` = '$app_fb_page_id' AND `app_type` = '$app_type'";
     $result_app_analytics_hits_sql = mysql_query($app_analytics_hits_sql) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
     while ($app_analytics_hits_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_app_analytics_hits_sql)) {       
         $app_hits_array[] = $app_analytics_hits_row;
     } 

     return $app_hits_array;
}
```

How can i generate a new array based on the unique records?, that stores, let's say in this case hits....

so i will need an array that will have:

```
browser || hits
chrome     30
safari     15
firefox    40
```

this should be generated preferentially from the first array that fetches all hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using aggregate MySQL functions, you could do...

```
$browserToHits = array();

foreach($results as $result) {
    $key = $result['browser'];

    if ( ! array_key_exists($key, $browserToHits)) {
        $browserToHits[$key] = 0;
    }

    $browserToHits[$key] += $result['hits'];

}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/gORYPgZ1).